problem displaying ICONE in search results
i tryed to use the link and hosting the icone on different hostersbut the problem is in the integratimg i cant find a solution. its a react web app
this is what i tryed exactly
`    
<!-- Favicon -->
<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" href="https://i.ibb.co/yWbGb9H/logoblack.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://i.ibb.co/yWbGb9H/logoblack.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.djebrilacademy.com/icone.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Djebril Academy</title>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "https://www.djebrilacademy.com",
    "logo": "https://www.djebrilacademy.com/icone.ico"
  }
</script>`


First try to use any other url for favicon, so it will be helpful you to clarify either issue with link or with your react app.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Djebril Academy</title>

    <!-- Favicon Links -->
    <link rel="icon" href="https://i.ibb.co/yWbGb9H/logoblack.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://i.ibb.co/yWbGb9H/logoblack.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="icon" href="https://www.djebrilacademy.com/icone.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- Tailwind CSS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <!-- JSON-LD Script -->
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "url": "https://www.djebrilacademy.com",
        "logo": "https://www.djebrilacademy.com/icone.ico"
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your React app will be injected here -->
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>



